# YarnClient getApplications : filtering on queue name

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to use the method [YarnClient#getApplications](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html#getApplications-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-java.util.EnumSet-) to retrieve applications from a YARN cluster, filtering on queue name. From the javadoc: "If any of the params is set to null, it is not used when filtering."

If I provide null for all arguments, I get back exactly what I would expect, all applications from all users of all types across all queues.

However, if I specify a Set of queue names, I never get anything back.

When I run YarnClient#getAllQueues I can clearly see the names of my queues when I log out the results. The following queues are visible from getAllQueues: root, root.default, root.TEST_QUEUE_A, root.TEST_QUEUE_B.

I have tried the following strings in order to get any results at all when specifying a Set of queue names. In all cases I provided an ImmutableSet.of() the string literals from the following list:

- root
- root.default
- TEST_QUEUE_A
- test_queue_a
- root.TEST_QUEUE_A
- root.test_queue_a

In all cases the calls succeed, and I am returned an empty List of ApplicationReport.

What else can I try in order to get a filtered list of applications from YARN?